# Bases for irreducible representations $V$ and $W$ are linearly independent implies basis for $V \oplus W$ is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho: G \to GL(U)$ be a reducible representation with dimension $n$ of a finite group $G$ such that $U= V \oplus W$, with $V$ and $W$ irreducible. If $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_k\}$ and $\{w_{k+1}, w_{k+2}, ... , w_n\}$ are two linearly independent bases for $V$ and $W$, respectively, is it true that $\{v_1, v_2,...,v_k, w_{k+1}, ..., w_n\}$ is linearly independent and a basis for $U$?

Comment: Yes of course. This is an elementary question about vector spaces, and does not involve $\rho$ at all.

Comment: Okay thank you I just wanted to explicitly make the connection with representations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$ spans $V$ and $\{w_1,\cdots,w_r\}$ spans $W$. This means every $v\in V$ is expressible as a linear combination $v=a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k$ and every $w\in W$ as $b_1w_1+\cdots+b_rw_r$ for some choices of scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_k,b_1,\cdots,b_r$. Suppose further $U=V+W$ is an internal sum, meaning every vector $u\in U$ is expressible as $u=v+w$ with $v\in V,w\in W$. Then $u$ may be further expressed as $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k+b_1w_1+\cdots+b_rw_r$, by using the expressions for $v$ and $w$. As $u$ is arbitrary, this means $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k,w_1,\cdots,w_r\}$ spans $U$.

Now suppose instead $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent in $V$, and $\{w_1,\cdots,w_r\}$ is linearly independent in $W$, and further that $V\oplus W$ is an internal direct sum inside $U$. This means that inside $U$ we can always say that $v+w=0$ with $v\in V,w\in W$ implies $v=w=0$. If we have any linear combination $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k+b_1w_1+\cdots+b_rw_r=0$ then as $V\oplus W$ is internal this implies that $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_kv_k=b_1w_1+\cdots+b_rw_r=0$ which since $\{v_i\}$ and $\{w_j\}$ are linearly independent implies $a_1,\cdots,a_k,b_1,\cdots,b_r$ are all $0$. Thus, $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k,w_1,\cdots,w_r\}$ is also linearly independent in $U$ under these hypotheses.

Thus, if $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{w_i\}$ is a basis for $W$, then their union is a basis for $V\oplus W$.

As mentioned in the comments, this is a basic fact of linear algebra (and so is a good exercise to do well before learning representation theory!).

Comment: Thanks! I definitely covered this in linear algebra, it was just about two years ago, things get rusty